# Swift Variable Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, generics, types

Is it possible in the current iteration of Swift (2.1) to add constraints on a variable type?

If I have a class `Element`

```
class Element: NSObject {
    var type: ElementType
    init(type: ElementType) {
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

with an enum `ElementType`

```
enum ElementType {
    case Cell
    case Header
    case Footer
    case Decoration(kind: String)
}
```

in some other class if I have a variable of type `Element`, is it at all possible to put constraints like:

```
var element: Element? where Self == .Header
```

or instead would I have to override `didSet`

```
var element: Element? {
    didSet {
        if let value = element where value.type == Decoration {
            element = Optional.None
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's not possible, the generic system isn't as powerful as I would like (being able to only constrain extensions by protocol and class inheritance for example and no variadic generic parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type constraints and types checks are a compilation feature but you want to check the runtime value of an object.

I am pretty sure that's impossible. You will have to use a runtime check (e.g. `willSet` or `didSet`).

Or, instead of enforcing the type by the value of a `type` atrribute, enforce it with a real type, e.g.

subclassing

```
class Header: Element
```

or make `Element` a protocol implemented by four separate classes:

```
protocol Element {
}

class Header: Element
```

(you can use protocol extension for shared functions).

Comment: That's too bad, I would love to see some sort of constraint filter feature with extensions where you can selectively apply extensions based on enum values for example

Comment: I originally made this library I'm making in objective-c so I did have a subclass structure where `Header` inherited from a common class `Element` but i kind of like associated enums too. who knows we'll see